# i can't decrypt or verify messages sent using Symantecs PGP using GPG Keychain

Tags: encryption, pgp, symantec

I'm not using command line, merely two separate GUI programs that should functionally work together, but I'm unable to both verify a signed file and decrypt a file sent to me by someone else using Symantec's PGP program and I'm using "GPG Keychain." They have my public key and I have theirs. Any idea why they're not working when they should be?